# How to fetch complete user details from Facebook API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

How to fetch complete userDetails from the Facebook API

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Uncomment to automatically sign in the user.
        _signInFacebook.delegate = self;
        _signInFacebook.readPermissions =  @[@"email",@"birthday"];

    }

- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"LOGGED IN TO FACEBOOK");
    [self fetchUserInfo];
}


-(void)fetchUserInfo {

    FBSDKAccessToken* token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",token.userID] parameters:@{ @"fields":@"id,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email,gender,location,picture.type(large),age_range,verified,birthday"}  HTTPMethod:@"GET"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

             if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",result);
                 [USERDEFAULTS setObject:result forKey:PROFILE_KEY];
             }

         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error fetchUserInfo %@",error);
         }
     }];

}
```

Expecting mobile number to fetch from facebook API

Comment: some of the Facebook attributes are private which so you would take permission to access these attributes. Birthday is one of them.

Comment: So I need have pass argument for permission to access user details.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "picture" instead of "photo" to get user profile photo. 
And you can get userID form the accessToken like:

```
FBSDKAccessToken* token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
NSString *ID = token.userID
```

When log in:
To get birthday, you need permission "user_birthday"
To get location, you need permission "user_location"

You can test everything in Facebook Graph API Explorer before implementing in your app.

To request for permission when logging in, sample code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager* login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_birthday"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    //your code to handle login result
}];
```

Comment: email,gender,id,name & picture worked!  birthday & location Not

Comment: after passing Token value unable to get birthday and mobile number.

Comment: @kiran When you login in your app, you need to request for the permissions. Did you try with the Facebook Graph API Explorer? Can you get data you want from it?

Comment: I used this refered url:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/ to set permission for the application.

Comment: @kiran when you login(request for a user token)in your app, you need to specify the permission you want.

Comment: @kiran answer updated, sample code added for permission

Comment: @kiran With the endpoint you referred in the url, you can't update your permission. You can only read what permission you have.

Comment: Finaly for  FBSDKLoginButton    _signInFacebook.delegate = self;
    _signInFacebook.readPermissions =  @[@"email",@"birthday"]; i got birthday .  but mobile not working.

Comment: I updated my question!  only pending with mobile number do not know what is the perfect parameter for it.

Comment: @kiran Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ I don't think you can get that, at least not from this endpoint.